# Is using Jquery's .on() function good practice? Or is there a better way

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Using .ajax() I am dynamically loading a list of images where the path is based on a "select" .trigger().

My "delete" function worked before loading the images on document ready but not after.
I was able to get it working again by using .on() but am wondering if there is a better way.

Is is good practice to use this function or should it be a last resort?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#displayGallery").change(function () {

//ajax

}).trigger('change');
});


$(document).on("click", ".deletepic", function(){

//ajax

return false;
});
```

Comment: It's 100% the opposite of a `last resort`, it's infact, `the staple` of event delegation. The only thing I would change is `document` to whatever closest static parent container you can find, simply for a performance increase.

Comment: ok cool thanks @Ohgodwhy . Just playing with Jquery and .ajax and wanting to learn best practices. Any recommended sources to for that?

Comment: Yes, I'd use stackoverflow's search bar and keywords describing your objective, it's likely already here. Other than that, trial and error is the best way to learn.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy for some reason using anything but document stops my code from working :(

Comment: @chris Then the chances are high that the selector for the jQuery object (upon which `on` was applied) returned no matches (or incorrect matches).

Comment: @user2246674 I got it working by putting the $(selector).on() inside $(document).ready() My example above shows them as separated. Im assuming .on inside .ready is the way to go

Comment: @chris Yes, this has been discussed *many* times before and has nothing special to do with `on` - the DOM (and said element) is guaranteed *after* ready, but not necessarily before.